# ExpandableListView from strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, expandablelistview, android-resources

Lately I've been trying to reorganize some menus with `ExpandableListView`, and got it working, but hardcoded. Right now I'm looking for a way to get the values from `strings.xml`, and ran into a few issues.

Here is what I have ATM.

This is for the headers.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  headersList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] parentHeaders = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headers);
    List<String> parentHeaders = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(headers));
    headersList.addAll(parentHeaders);

    HashMap<String, List<String>> allChildItems = returnGroupedChildItems();
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    ExpandableListViewAdapter expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), headersList, allChildItems);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListViewAdapter);
}
```

Instead of that, I want to populate it with the following fragment from my strings-arrays:

```
<string-array name = "headers">
  <item>@string/parent1</item>
  <item>@string/parent2</item>
  <item>@string/parent3</item>
</string-array>
```

Finally, I have this one for the childs:

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> returnGroupedChildItems()
{
  HashMap<String, List<String>> childList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  List<String> parent1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] child1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent1);
    List<String> childHeaders1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(child1));
    parent1.addAll(childHeaders1);

  List<String> parent2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] child2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent2);
    List<String> childHeaders2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(child2));
    parent1.addAll(childHeaders2);

  List<String> parent3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] child3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent3);
    List<String> childHeaders3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(child3));
    parent3.addAll(childHeaders3);

  childList.put(headersList.get(0), parent1);
  childList.put(headersList.get(1), parent2);
  childList.put(headersList.get(2), parent3);

  return childList;
}
```

Likewise, I have 3 other string-arrays with all those values.

```
<string-array name = "parent1">
  <item>@string/child1_1</item>
  <item>@string/child1_2</item>
  <item>@string/child1_3</item>
  <item>@string/child1_4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name = "parent2">
  <item>@string/child2_1</item>
  <item>@string/child2_2</item>
  <item>@string/child2_3</item>
  <item>@string/child2_4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name = "parent3">
  <item>@string/child3_1</item>
  <item>@string/child3_2</item>
  <item>@string/child3_3</item>
  <item>@string/child3_4</item>
</string-array>
```

Been trying to use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent1)` but it doesn't work.

Also this, my Adapter, if it helps.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

  private Context context;
  private List<String> parentDataSource;
  private HashMap<String, List<String>> childDataSource;

  public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> childParent, HashMap<String, List<String>> child)
  {
    this.context = context;
    this.parentDataSource = childParent;
    this.childDataSource = child;
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount()
  {
    return this.parentDataSource.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
  {
    return this.childDataSource.get(this.parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
  {
    return parentDataSource.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
  {
    return this.childDataSource.get(parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
  {
    return groupPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
  {
    return childPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds()
  {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null)
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
    }
    String parentHeader = (String)getGroup(groupPosition);
    TextView parentItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    parentItem.setText(parentHeader);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null)
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
    }
    String childName = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView childItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
    childItem.setText(childName);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Finally, managed to put this together. I can populate my list directly from strings. So, my last question would be, how can I make a loop that checks my parent array, gets it's name and populate each child with the corresponding array?

Edit 3: Did some changes on my loop. It's still hard coded, but it works wihout the need of extra variables (albeit, using lots of *ifs*).

```
int size = headersList.size();

for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
  {
  List<String> childList = new ArrayList<>();
  if (i == 1)
    {
      String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent1);
      List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
      childList.addAll(childHeaders);
    } else if (i == 2)
    {
      String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent2);
      List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
      childList.addAll(childHeaders);
    } else if (i == 3)
    {
      String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent3);
      List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
      childList.addAll(childHeaders);
    }

    childContent.put(headersList.get(i - 1), childList);
  }
```

As I said, this works, and populates my lists with the expected values, but I would like to do it without all the conditions (I only need to dynamically pass each parent# array to my *child* *String*).

So, my last question would be, is there a way to, in each iteration of the loop, retrieve headersList.get(i-1), and use that name inside getStringArray()?

Comment: Please show the code that you tried that isn't working

Comment: Did you implement `ExpandableListViewAdapter` yourself? If so, please show that class...

Comment: The last one I tried was this (As suggested in one of the answers)

        String [] headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headers);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(headers));
        parentHeaderInformation.add(list);

As for the adapter, adding it to the main question.

Comment: I don't know what `parentHeaderInformation` is in your comment, but you must add a list to another list using `addAll`, not `add`

Comment: Yes, using add.All solved it! didn't have to overload my constructor, asi it is currently doing what I wanted. I edited the main question to reflect that, so now the only thing left to do is a loop to automate the process a little.  
Anyway, thanks for all the help, I'm so close to finishing it.

Comment: I still think my answer below should work

Comment: Can't test that bit of code right now, but it catches my attention that the array "parent1" is hardcoded in there.

Comment: It must be hard-coded, your piece of `R.array.parent(i)` depends on a string name, but there is a workable solution in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

`getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent1)` will return `String []` and not `List<String>`. To convert the `String []` to List, please use the following

```
String [] parent1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parent1);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(parent1));
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried to do just that, but then when i use  

    String [] headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headers);  
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(headers));  
    headersList.add(list);  it tells me the following "**add** (java.lang.String) in **List** cannot be aplied to (java.util.List<java.lang.String>".

Comment: Seems your headerList is a List of strings used to display group titles. I have given the list for children. You should add this to the HashMap. 



 HashMap<String, List<String>> childList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  // assume your headersList is filled with titles
  childList.put(headersList.get(0), parent1); // parent1 is retrieved from string array 
  childList.put(headersList.get(1), parent2);
  childList.put(headersList.get(2), parent3);

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overload your constructor

```
public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> childParent, HashMap<String, List<String>> child)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.parentDataSource = childParent;
    this.childDataSource = child;
}

public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] childParent, HashMap<String, String[]> child) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.parentDataSource = Arrays.asList(childParent);
    this.childDataSource = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : child.entrySet()) {
        childDataSource.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue());
    } 
}
```

And to answer

> but I would like to do it without all the conditions (I only need to dynamically pass each parent# array to my child String).
>
> So, my last question would be, is there a way to, in each iteration of the loop, retrieve headersList.get(i-1), and use that name inside getStringArray()?

Yes, `getResources().getIdentifier`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Resources res = getResources();

    // Build Hashmap 
    Map<String, String[]> allChildItems = new HashMap<>();
    String[] headersList = res.getStringArray(R.array.headers);
    for (String header : headersList) {
        int resId = res.getIdentifier(header, "array", getPackageName());
        allChildItems.put(header, res.getStringArray(resId));
    }

    // Build adapter
    ExpandableListViewAdapter expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, headersList, allChildItems);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListViewAdapter);
}
```

(code untested)

Comment: Tried using that. Still no luck calling the strings from my xml into my ExpandableListView. Also, on the second call to ExpadableListViewAdapter (The one you suggested) it tells me the constructor is never used.

Comment: It's never used because you never call it...  That's a warning, not an error. The point is that you want the same functionality between an array and an Arraylist... Your Adapter needs List objects, not arrays, but that doesn't stop you from passing in arrays and making them into lists

Comment: Ok, will have that in mind, thanks for the help. Currently I have to leave, but later will try that and keep you informed if I solved my problem.

Comment: Tried to use that piece of code, to no avail. Still, managed to pull something in my method. Already edited my original question with this new information. 

And maybe what you answered is what I need, but couldn't get it to work (Maybe I'm just a little dense with java).

Comment: You don't need if else statements. My answer already handles getting the different resources. I'll test later today

Comment: The issue with that approach is that it needs the arraysnto be called parent. I was thinking doing something else directly on my strings.xml: adding a second array, and populate it with atrays, so I can call upon that when populating childs.

Comment: I see. That seems like it. Will try to make it work when I get home.

Comment: Ok, tried to use it, but I'm running into an issue: allChildren is not declared. Also, would it be okay to insert my previous HashMap into the TODO?

Comment: You could not spot the typo? `allChildItems` == `allChildren`

Comment: Corrected that bit, and now in the second to last line it finds an error in the arguments for _new ExpandableListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, headersList, allChildItems)_. Basically, the expected parameters should be <java.lang.String>, and the actual parameters are of type (java.lang.String[]).

One last question, at the end, should I call _return allChildItems;_?

Comment: no... Why would you return? This code is intended for `onCreate`. And that method is `void`, so no return... As for the other error, the constructor in my question has the correct types.

Comment: Moved the code to onCreate, directly under headersList, then added the extra peice to my constructor. Still getting an error on the same line, _Cannot resolve constructor 'ExpandableViewAdapter(test.com.elv.MainActivity, java.lang.String[], java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]>)'.